# Quicksort, comparator function explanation

Tags: quicksort, comparator

my teacher gave me this code that is used for quicksort which I can't understand and I need to. Could you give me a detailed explanation about it? Thanks

```
int comparator(const void* e1, const void* e2) { 
   char* s1 = *(char**)e1; 
   char* s2 = *(char**)e2; 
   return strcmp(s1, s2); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Quicksort you need to provide a function to compare elements and order them - the return value from the function explains how the two elements being compared should be ordered.

As explained at e.g. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/

In your case, your teacher has provided the comparator function which compares the string pointed at when you treat its parameters as an array of strings and compare the first string in each case.